# Rails redirect_to SyntaxError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Well, I'm not a web developer. Just a curious and programming enthusiast.

I was trying to learn ruby on rails following this tutorial: [Ruby on Rails 3.2 Blog in 15 minutes step by step](http://www.reinteractive.net/posts/32-ruby-on-rails-3-2-blog-in-15-minutes-step-by-step).

I've accomplished almost all of it, but when I was configuring the comments I started having some problems. First of all, I'm using a different version of rails (4.0.4), so I had to change a little bit my app/controllers/comments_controller.rb. The code recommended by the article was:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
        def create
                @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
                @comment = @post.comments.create!(params[:comment])
                redirect_to @post
        end
end
```

The code with the tweak that I had to made:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
            @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
            @comment = @post.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit(:comment_text,:link)
            redirect_to @post

  end
end
```

But I'm getting the following message:

> SyntaxError in CommentsController#create
>   /Users/gustavorpaiva/quick_blog/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' redirect_to @post ^
>
> Rails.root: /Users/gustavorpaiva/quick_blog

I would really appreciate if someone could gie me a hand here. It's probably a real silly mistake, but I just don't know what else to do...

Thanks!

Comment: That error is saying you're missing a closing parenthesis `)` on the `@post.comments.create!` line in your second code block.

Comment: omg I can't believe i didn't see that..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the second line of your `create` definition, the line should look as follows:

```
@comment = @post.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit(:comment_text,:link))
```